# Dompdf while loop - only the last record is converted to pdf

Tags: php, dompdf

```
<?php require"../db_connection1.php";?>
<?php require"../db_connection4.php";?>
<?php require"../db_connection5.php";?>
<?php

require_once('../dompdf/autoload.inc.php') ;
use Dompdf\Dompdf ;
ob_start() ;

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  
    $payroll_date    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection5, $_POST["payroll_date"]) ;
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM  ".$payroll_date."  ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection5, $query);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
    $Employee_Number   = $row1[0] ;
}


?>           
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    .SECTION-1 { 
      margin-top:110px ;    
      margin-left: 108px ;
      margin-bottom: 5px ;
    }
  </style>
</head> 
<body>
  <form action = "#" method ="POST">
  <div class ="SECTION-1" > 

  <?php

  $query_hr_data = "SELECT * FROM applicants_final WHERE employee_number = '{$Employee_Number}' ";

  $result = mysqli_query($connection4, $query_hr_data );
  while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $cost_center         =   $row5['cost_center'] ;
    $position            =   $row5['position'] ;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  ".$payroll_date."  WHERE EE_NUMBER = '{$Employee_Number}' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection5, $query);

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $EE_NUMBER         =   $row1['EE_NUMBER'] ;
      $EE_NAME           =   $row1['EE_NAME'] ;

      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM  ".$payroll_date."  WHERE EE_NUMBER = '{$Employee_Number}' ";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection1, $query);

      while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $LATES_UNDERTIME_HRS   =   $row2['LATES_UNDERTIME'] ;
        $ABSENCES_HRS          =   $row2['ABSENCES'] ;



        echo "<table id ='heading'>" ;

        echo"<tr>" ;
        echo"<th id ='heading-2-1'>EE Name </th>" ;
        echo"<td id ='heading-2'>" .$row1['EE_NAME']." </br> </td>" ;
        echo"<th id ='heading-2-1'>Philhealth # </th>" ;
        echo"<td id ='heading-2'>" .$philhealth_number." </br> </td>" ;
        echo"</tr>" ;

        echo"<tr>" ;
        echo"<th id ='heading-2-1'>Basic_Salary </th>" ;
        echo"<td id ='heading-2'>" .number_format($basic_salary,2). "</br> </td>" ;
        echo"<th id ='heading-2-1'> Allowances </th>" ;
        echo"<td id ='heading-2'>" .number_format($deminimis_benefits,2)."</br> </td>" ;
        echo"</tr>" ;

        echo "</table>" ;
        echo "<table id='design-8'>" ;

        echo"<tr>" ;
        echo"<th>Lates_Undertime ( minutes ) </th>" ;
        echo"<td>" .$LATES_UNDERTIME_HRS. "</br> </td>" ;
        echo"<td>" .$LATES_UNDERTIME." </br> </td>" ;
        echo"</tr>" ;

        echo"<tr>" ;
        echo"<th>Absences </th>" ;
        echo"<td>" .$ABSENCES_HRS." </br> </td>" ;
        echo"<td>" .$ABSENCES." </br> </td>" ;
        echo"</tr>" ;


        echo "</table>" ;
        echo "<div id='design-2'> *** Payslip Confidential *** </div>" ;

  ?>        
  </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper(array(0, 0, 612, 1100), 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();

    $pdf = $dompdf->output();
    $file_location = "C:/wamp/www/dbs-program/payroll-program/version-3.4/pdfReports/".$Employee_Number.".pdf" ;
    file_put_contents($file_location, $pdf);

    }

  }

}

?>
```

Thanks Brian, I updated the code, I just remove redundant data so it will 
 not be too long. Thanks  again for taking another looked.

I want to print 50 plus pdf and save it to the designated folder with pdf name as Employee number coming from 
 mysql database. Now the issue is only last data in the while loop is being 
 converted to pdf, if i transfer the closing bracket of the first query to 
 the last code after html, the pdf converted is only the first one. When I 
 echo $Employee_Number = $row1[0] I get all the 50+ data. I already tried
 iterations such as for, but it becomes more complicated since it print out 
 the exact number of pdf's but with no data being printed,  Hoping somebody 
 a help or hint on how to proceed. Thank you ahead.

Comment: You should include a more complete sample of your code (e.g. whats the while loop doing?).

Comment: This looks like a structural issue with your PHP not a dompdf issue. You should spend more time reviewing your logic and please, _please_, *please* try and format your code. Not only does it help us when reviewing your question but it can help you find issues in the logic. What you had was a bit of a mess. I did what I could but there are some basic structural issues (e.g. opening your HTML outside the while, closing inside).